# LaTeX Error: File `makecellcaption.sty' not found

Tags: errors, captions

I´m having this error whith some makecellcaption file I do not know. I´m using overleaf. This is my code (just post the packages, I have tables, graphs but my full document is big):
Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{array }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=30mm,
 right=30mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon}
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{Panel~\Alph{subtable}}



\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs


\begin{document}
hi


 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your second line, you have `\usepackage{makecell caption}`.  If you want two different packages, separate them with a comma, not a space.  It might even be better to use separate imports and comment why you're using the package:

```
\usepackage{makecell} % to have special column headings
\usepackage{caption} % to have captions of things that don't float
```

That will help you to avoid ending up with a humongously long preamble that you don't need.

Comment: BTW, hyperref should always be the last (or nearly last) package loaded.